# function to provide id of interval the input is located between

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to create a function that will receive a date as input and be able to provide back the id of the corresponding interval that it's located in.

For example with this table here:

```
  id |   start    |    end   
  -- +------------+------------

  1  | 2000-11-30 | 2001-02-19

  2  | 2001-02-21 | 2001-06-04

  3  | 2001-06-05 | 2001-07-13

  4  | 2001-07-15 | 2001-11-29
```

If i input the date '2001-04-17', i want it to return back the id value of 2.

i'm currently trying this currently but can't get it to work:

```
create or replace function getId(_date date) returns integer
as $$
declare
    myId integer;
begin
    set myId = (select id from myTable 
        where ((_date >= start) and (_date <= end)));

    return myId;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `id` directly without setting to `myId`. And`end` is the PostgreSQL keyword, so you should use it inside double quotes `""`

```
create or replace function getId(_date date) returns integer
as $$
begin
    return (select id from myTable 
        where ((_date >= start) and (_date <= "end")));
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
```

Call the function:

```
select getId('2001-04-17');

Output: 2
```